# Model INA128 for Proteus

Tags: proteus

The Proteus 7.7 does not have a model for **INA128**. 
I also need this model for the Ares (**INA128 SMD**).

Is there any library with it so I can add or I need to create this model?

Answer (score 1):

The INA128 from [TI has PSPICE models](http://www.ti.com/product/INA128/toolssoftware). TI makes their [own simulator](http://www.ti.com/tool/tina-ti), so it's unlikely you'd find one from them to support your competing simulator. You'll need to make the model yourself.

Comment: Do you know any good tutorial for this?

Comment: @EdDc Nope, I'd just [Google it](http://bit.ly/1yjqqBg).

Comment: @Samuel, please don't post bit.ly links. Nobody can tell where they lead to.

Comment: @ThePhoton There is a really easy way to find out where it leads; *follow it*. Note that URLs count against the character limit (though I think they shouldn't). So, even though it was not required in this case, it helps avoid going over the limit.

Comment: @Samuel I asked a good tutorial because I did not find any that would create a model for Proteus and Ares.

Comment: @EdDc I recommend asking a separate question about creating the model for Proteus and Ares.